# Iterate over files located in different folders

Tags: python, file, loops

I’d like to write a function to iterate over excel files that are in different folders. Parts of the path of each file are the same, for instance:

C:\Main\Division\Reports\Year\Data.xls

The only part of each path that changes is ‘Year’.  The files all have the same name.

Is there a way to do this with a placeholder for Year?  If not, what approach should I take?

Comment: To clarify, do you need to iterate over all the directories in the parent directory (C:\Main\Division\Reports\)?

Comment: `from pathlib import Path` then `for p in Path(r'C:\Main\Division\Reports').glob('*/Data.xls'): do_stuff(p)`

Comment: @Sach I'd like to pull data from 1 file located in each Year folder

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for your reply. I received an OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. It seems .glob referenced the first folder listed in the Reports directory instead of the one I need

Comment: @BeginnerKruman hm, I wrote that quickly and used unix syntax in the glob argument. Try using windows syntax. I don't really have a windows box to experiment with atm...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) function

```
directory = "C:\Main\Division\Reports"
root_dir = os.path.dirname(directory)
for data in os.listdir(directory):
      file_name = os.path.join(root_dir, data, 'Data.xls')
      # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try os.walk

```
import os

parent = "C:\Main\Division\Reports"

for root, directory, files in os.walk(parent):
    print root
    print directory
    print files
```